# Python Improperly configured URL

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python and Django development. I'm using Python 3.4.0 and Django 1.7.3.
I am following the django docs tutorials, everything is working fine until part 3 of the tutorial. In part 3, when I make my view I'm getting the error(screenshot attached.)

[image]
Following is my urls.py of application 'polls'

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from polls import views

urlpatters = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Following is my urls.py of the main project.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I'm not able to find where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled `patterns` in `polls/urls.py`.

Django relies on there being a `patterns` variable in the `urls` module, but in your case you accidentally put `urlpatters`.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Just a heads up, you don't need to use `patterns` unless you are using function based views and you are using the string import. [It is deprecated in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns) and can be replaced by a standard list instead.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This will work in all versions of Django, and you won't have to worry about it breaking in the near future.

Comment: oops. I'm embarrased now. Thanks for the astute answer.